# How to crop image to new file?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, crop

I'm using the Crop (C) tool to crop 3 or 4 images out of a larger image. After I crop each image and save it, I have to hit undo a bunch of times to uncrop it and get back to the original image. I'd rather just crop the image to a new file/tab. Is that possible?

Comment: Just discovered Revert (F12) but it doesn't work after I do a Save As!

Comment: Would it be better to select fragment of a image and copy it to a new file? You will get orginal untouched and than You can work (ex. precise crop)on new file.

Comment: @AdamRichardSon: Hrm? If I could duplicate the file 3 times before I do the cropping, that would work fine. Is there a hotkey for that? This needs to be efficient; I've got 1000s of photos to go through.

Comment: In PS You can make a hotkey for almost everything by Yourself. GO to hotkey menu & make one.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of cropping just use the selector in Photoshop, select the area you want, EDIT >> COPY and then go paste into a new tab.

Comment: Writen in the same time! :)

Comment: You mean the Selection Tool/Marquee? My photos are slightly rotated, so I want to use the Crop tool to rotate and crop them in one shot.

Comment: Yes that tool. Once you paste it in a new doc you can rotate all you want. The use of Crop is overkill.

Comment: Rotate the original image as you need >> Select Area >> Copy >> Paste into new Doc.

Comment: Or if your more comfortable with Crop then open the History viewer and after you do your crop click on the top of the history to return to the original image in one keystroke.

Comment: @xXPhenom22Xx: How is it overkill? Rotate it via what tool?? All the images might be rotated slightly differently. Only your last comment is remotely viable.

Comment: You can rotate an image by going into EDIT >> TRANSFORM >> ROTATE I believe. This will allow you to manipulate the position of the original image. The use the marquee tool and select your area and copy/paste...

Comment: In either event there are multiple ways to skin a cat and get the result you want. You can crop and then revert or you can use copy/paste. The rotating of images that has to be done with either solution just one has less steps to return you back to your starting point

Comment: Just a word of note that if you have multiple layers and smartobjects, you have to use Copy Merged (Shift+Ctrl+C) instead.